# Is there a way to add display annotation to the buffer text so that it's searchable?

Tags: isearch, text-properties, overlays

Suppose I have a text data file with various data values which the computer can parse easily, but it's not easy to read for a human.

In order to make the file easier to read I'd  add display only annotation automatically to the file, e.g. like this:

```
3,10,'test',...
```

becomes

```
id = 3, length = 10, title = 'test', ...
```

These field labels can be added with, e.g. the before-string  property. This works fine.

But what if I'd also like to search the file with isearch, but I don't just want to search for values (e.g. 'test'), but also the field names (e.g. title)?

Currently, this does not work, because the before-string is not part of the buffer text, so  it's not searchable by isearch.

Is there a way somehow to add such field names to the file for display purposes, so they are not part of the file, and also make it possible to search these display names with isearch?

Is there some property which makes it possible for isearch to consider these added texts too when searching?

Comment: Another way to solve this is to actually convert the buffer to the more verbose format when reading and convert it back to the more terse when saved. See `revert-buffer-function` and `write-contents-functions`. The advantage is that normal search work straight out of the box.

Comment: @Lindydancer interesting idea and simple solution, though it may cause problems when I copy parts of the file. Then I'll copy the verbose version which is invalid data. So then copying also needs to be monitored and fixed.

Comment: It depends -- if you copy it to a buffer that use the same major mode, it will be encoded using `write-contents-functions` when you save that buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (based on your comment to this answer), you want to search within some text that has a given *overlay property* (`before-string`) with a particular value. That is, you want search to skip over all text that does not have that property with that value.

You can do this with library [**`isearch-prop.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el).
See the online description [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearch-prop.elFeatures).

---

`before-string` is an *overlay* property, *not a text* property. Overlay properties are attached to *buffer positions*. Text properties are attached to *characters* in the buffer.

You apparently want to search for a sequence of chars in a buffer such that there is a particular overlay property value at the buffer position of each matched char.

You can do this with [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el), using command **`isearchp-property-forward`**, which is bound to **`C-t`** during Isearch. (You also have command `isearchp-property-forward-regexp`, bound to `C-M-t`.)

The first time you use it:

1. You're prompted for whether to search the buffer areas that have a given text property value or a given overlay value, or both. At the prompt, you enter `overlay`, to search only overlays.
2. Then you're prompted for the overlay property. With the first example code below, you'd enter `my-ov-prop`.
3. Then you're prompted for the value of that overlay property. With the first example, you'd enter `foobar` to search the areas that have property `my-ov-prop` with value `foobar`. (Hit an empty `RET` when you're done entering values.)
4. Then type the text you want to find in those areas. This is regular Isearch, but restricted to the buffer areas that have that overlay with that value.

```lisp
(let ((ov1  (make-overlay 137 165))
      (ov2  (make-overlay 210 217))
      (ov3  (make-overlay 346 366)))
  (overlay-put ov1 'my-ov-prop 'foobar)
  (overlay-put ov2 'my-ov-prop 'toto)
  (overlay-put ov3 'my-ov-prop 'foobar)
  (message "OV1: %S, OV2: %S, OV3: %S" ov1 ov2 ov3))
```

Same thing for overlay property `before-string`:

```lisp
(let ((ov4  (make-overlay 6 18))
      (ov5  (make-overlay 22 35))
      (ov6  (make-overlay 44 58)))
  (overlay-put ov4 'before-string "tata")
  (overlay-put ov5 'before-string "ubub")
  (overlay-put ov6 'before-string "tata")
  (message "OV4: %S, OV5: %S, OV6: %S" ov4 ov5 ov6))
```

At the first prompt, enter `overlay`. At the second prompt enter `before-string`. At the third prompt enter the string `"tata"` (and then an empty extra `RET`).

Then search for whatever you want in the areas of text that have property `before-string` with value `"tata"`.

(The reason for hitting the extra `RET`, to say you're done entering values for the property, is because some properties, in particular `face`, allow multiple values, which get merged. Property `before-string` uses only one value.)

To *repeat the same search* you need not go through the prompting again. Just use **`C-u C-t`** during Isearch.  (But as always with Isearch, to be able to use a prefix arg you need to set option `isearch-allow-prefix` to non-`nil`.)

If you ever want to search the text that's *outside* your propertied areas, instead of inside, just use **`M-= ~`**, to toggle searching within/outside those zones.

---

Here's the doc string of `isearchp-property-forward`:

> **`isearchp-property-forward`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> [**`isearch-prop.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el).
>
> `(isearchp-property-forward ARG)`
>
> Isearch forward in text with a text property or overlay property.
>
> That is, move to the next such property and search within it for text matching your input.
>
> Bound to **`C-t`** during Isearch.
>
> If `isearchp-complement-domain-p` is non-`nil` then move to the next
> zone that does **not** have the given property.  (Use **`M-= ~`** during
> Isearch to toggle this variable.)  For example, this lets you *search
> for text that is **NOT** displayed using a certain face* or combination of
> faces.
>
> With no prefix argument, or if you have not previously used an Isearch
> command that searches properties or applies them, you are *prompted* for
> the following:
>
> - the property type (`text`, `overlay`, or `text and overlay`)
> - the property (e.g., `face`, `mumamo-major-mode`)
> - the property values (e.g., a list of faces, for property `face`)
>
> If you have previously used such an Isearch property command, then a
> **prefix arg means reuse** the property type, property, and value from the
> last Isearch property command.  This includes `isearchp-property-*`
> commands and commands such as `isearchp-imenu*`,
> `isearchp-thing(-regexp)`, `isearchp-regexp-context-search`, and
> `isearchp-put-prop-on-region`.
>
> Note that this means that you can simply *use **`C-u C-t`** during ordinary
> Isearch in order **to repeat*** the last property search.
>
> The particular **prefix arg** controls the behavior as follows:
>
> - Plain `C-u`: Reuse the last property type (overlay, text, or both).
> - *Positive* prefix arg (e.g., `C-9`): Search only *text* properties.
> - *Negative* prefix arg (e.g., `C--`): Search only *overlay* properties.
> - *Zero* prefix arg (`C-0`): Search both *text and overlay* properties.
>
> By default, an actual value of the property matches the value
> you specify if it is `equal`.  Properties `mumamo-major-mode` and
> `face` (or `font-lock-face`) are exceptions.
>
> - For `mumamo-major-mode`, you specify the major mode whose zones of
>   text you want to search.  The actual property value is a list whose
>   car is the major mode symbol.
> - *For properties `face` and `font-lock-face`, you can pick **multiple
>   faces***, using completion (hit `RET` with empty input to finish
>   choosing).  Text is searched that has a face property that includes
>   any of the faces you choose.  If you choose no face (empty input at
>   the outset), then text with any face at all is searched.
>
> NOTE: If you search zones of property `face` and the property values include `font-lock` faces, then you might want to first make sure the entire buffer has been fontified.  You can do that
> using command `isearchp-fontify-buffer-now`.
>
> NOTE: This command is available during normal Isearch, on key `C-t`.  However, in order *to be able to use a prefix arg* within Isearch, *you must set `isearch-allow-scroll` or `isearch-allow-prefix`*
> (if available) to non-`nil`.  Otherwise, a prefix arg *exits*
> Isearch.

---

If, instead of wanting to search propertied text, you wanted to *search for* some text that has certain text properties, then, starting with Emacs 27, you can use command `text-property-search-forward`.  (Load library `text-property-search.el'.)  But I think it works only for *text* properties, *not* for overlay properties.

Comment: I want to use isearch to search the text of the file and also at the same time the text values of the properties (e.g. a strings added with before-string)  like they were part of the file. So from the questions example if I have this in the file: title = 'test' where test is part of the file and title is a string added with before-string, then I want to find this part with isearch both when I search for 'tit', for example, and also when I type 'tes'.

Comment: Yes, my answer lets you do this kind of thing. You search for the buffer text you want within only the overlaid buffer zones. Search skips all text that doesn't have the particular `before-string` overlay value (string).